# How to reference/require a parent controller in an AngularJS controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Require the parent controller instance works for directives, where you are able to get the parent directive using the require section of the directive config and later access the controller during link().

However this injected parent controller is not accessible while the controller is first executing (as linker will run afterwards).

So it there any other way to find a specific controller class up the DOM parent chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider an approach angular uses in their select directive where they have an init function in the controller that's called from the directive link function and passes another controller in as a parameter. See line 230 here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/select.js

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this approach, and I thought of this only as a fallback plan, since this means that I'll have to give up the controller's closure block for safeguarding data integrity: over this init() method whatver caller could pass in whatever value.